# Yii - parsing custom urls

Tags: php, regex, yii

I have a need to parse custom url's into data. The urls might look like this:

```
http://host.com/categoryXXX/brandYYY/markZZZ/page/1/otherparameters/othervalues
```

Where the first three parameters are basically prefix+value pairs (category - prefix, XXX - value). They might not all be present except for the first one (category).

All of the other parameters are optional and may or may not be present, and they also come in pairs 'key/value', AKA the usual path format of Yii.

I honestly have no idea how to parse such complex urls. Basically, I need a proper urlManager rule and a working mechanism to parse them.

Will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\/category(?P<category_id>[^\/]*)(?:\/brand(?P<brand_id>[^\/]*))?(?:\/mark(?P<mark_id>[^\/]*))?/i
```

This will create named captures for all of the fields you are looking for.  brand_id and mark_id are optional

Working version:
http://regex101.com/r/fQ7mU0/3

Comment: Can it be modified so that the mark and brand are interchangeable?

Comment: If you don't know what order they are in, just run separate regexs.

**Category:**
    /\/category(?P<category_id>[^\/\?]*)/i

**Brand:**
    /\/brand(?P<brand_id>[^\/\?]*)/i

**Mark:**
    /\/mark(?P<mark_id>[^\/\?]*)/i